# Purpose of using setuid() in SUID programs

Tags: security, privileges, setuid

I wonder that an SUID program like `passwd` is using the `setuid()` function call. Why does it drop root privileges?

Against what types of attack does this help? Buffer-overflow?

Comment: I don't think `passwd` does call setuid() to drop privileges, but it does have the setuid bit set so that it will *escalate* privileges when executed.  At least, that is the important thing to understand about passwd in this regard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First I'll discuss the setuid bit, which passwd uses and is distinct from the `setuid()` system call (which passwd does not use).  There is perhaps some confusion in the question in this regard.

It is not a protection against a buffer overflow, it's *vunerable* to such, or basically anything which would allow an attacker to use a privileged process for some nefarious unintended purpose.  This is because the setuid bit is the opposite of "dropping privileges"; it *bestows* root privileges, but only to the *process* and not the actual user.  That includes `passwd`.

That form of setuid requires the filesystem setuid bit set on the executable; `passwd` has this because it needs privileges to read and write `/etc/passwd`.  However, we hope passwd does not have any known security vulnerabilities (eg, potential overflow exploit) that would allow a nefarious person to get it do something other than reading and writing /etc/passwd (and other than doing that properly!), since it does run as root, and therefore *could* do anything -- except it is designed to do only one specific thing, and getting it to do anything else *should* (again, hopefully) be impossible.

So **using setuid in that sense is not protection against anything**, but it is often discussed in relation to vulnerabilities because potential vunerabilities are very important WRT setuid executables.

BUT: the setuid bit sets the [euid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_user_ID#Effective_user_ID) and not the actual uid, so it is actually parallel to the `seteuid()` system call and *not* `setuid()`.

There is an opposite form of "setuid" that is about dropping privileges, which involves the actual `setuid()` system call and does not require the setuid bit. This is when a process running as root (because root or sudo started it) changes its uid to a less privileged user.  Servers and daemons often do this if they need root privileges at start up (eg, to open a privileged port) but not subsequently.  That way if the server subsequently gets jacked, it does not have superuser privileges.  You cannot call `setuid(0)` and get root privileges back (but you can with set***e***uid).

Comment: thank you, the last paragraph is the most valuable for me, but the explanation is very good, thank you

Comment: You deserve more upvotes for this great answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply a preventative measure. Any app could potentially be vulnerable to any exploit conceivable if miscoded. The trick to reducing the possible damage is to perform actions with the least privileges required. Dropping running as root when not needed is an excellent start.